# Browser not refreshing its cached JavaScript and CSS files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-9, iis-7.5

It seems like IE is not able to detect that time stamps of JS and CSS files have changed, and it should now invalidate it's cache.

I think, this is something that should have been handled by the browser and server.

Please suggest ways that I could debug this issue, and/or probably fix this issue.

I prefer not use "hacky" solution like adding timestamps to URL of all the resources. One less thing to maintain!

- Setup: IIS 7.5 server hosting ASP.NET MVC website
- Deployment: Simple XCopy; JS and CSS are also being bundled.
- Client: IE9 (not specific, but this is what is being used currently)

We recently implemented ASP.NET's bundling and minification. I think it should do the trick.

From http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification,

> Once you update one file in a bundle, a new token is generated for the
>   bundle query string parameter and the full bundle must be downloaded
>   the next time a client requests a page containing the bundle. In
>   traditional markup where each asset is listed individually, only the
>   changed file would be downloaded. Assets that change frequently may
>   not be good candidates for bundling.